# Split an array into two, based on separator element

Tags: arrays, swift, split

I have an array of strings and I'd like to split that into two. An array containing the elements before the separator, and another one after it.

```swift
let sourceArray = ["items that", "are", "split", "by a string"]
// String that splits this array: "split"
// Expected output: [["items that", "are"], ["by a string"]]
```

I tried joining the array into a string and using `.components()`, but that removes the actual elements of the original array. Is there a way to do this using a built-in method or do I need to loop over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let sourceArray = ["items that", "are", "split", "by a string"]

let index = sourceArray.split(separator: "split").map { Array($0) }

print(index)
```

Comment: op doesn't mention that use case at least we expect it has one separator

Comment: Easy fix is to use the extended version of the function:  `let singleSplit = sourceArray.split(separator: "split", maxSplits: 1, omittingEmptySubsequences: false)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way :

```
var sourceArray = ["items that", "are", "split", "by a string"];
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
var firstArray = true;
for (var i = 0; i<sourceArray.lenght; i++){
   if (sourceArray[i]!=="split") {
      if (firstArray){
          array1.push(sourceArray[i]);
      }
      else {
          array2.push(sourceArray[i]);
      }
   }
   else {
      firstArray = false;
   }
```

}

At the end of the loop, just join the two arrays into a third one if you want it like that : [array1,array2].

Comment: This c++ code is very discouraged in swift , you should always utilize new high level functions as it will offer performant & compact code

Comment: Yes you're right, It's better to use the split method for example as you mentionned it. I just wanted to show another way to do it.

Comment: The question also specifically says without looping through the array.